# Loading JSON files in React, without JSON extension

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to require some JSON files in my React app (based on CRA 3.01 with Typescript).

The normal `const obj = require('./path/file.json')` would work if my files had a .json extension - however, these files have .md for 'metadata' and a couple other extensions, and the standard require isn't working. The files are from a tool, so changing to .json isn't a practical option.

Doing some research, it seems the approach is to use the webpack json-loader module (the webpack json-loader docs says that working with different file extensions is the main reason for using the module). I found an example and am using this:

```
const context = require.context(
  "json-loader!./metadata",
  true,
  /^\.\/.*\.md$/
);
const metadata = context("./foo.md");
```

I've got a minimum reproduction here (see App.tsx):
https://github.com/ericsolberg/testjson

It seems that this is correctly using the json-loader, and finding the file correctly. However, I'm getting a syntax error:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/json-loader/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/***/projects/jsontest/node_modules/json-loader/index.js:4:49)
```

I did some research on this error, and believe the problem is that the file is being parsed twice - first by the loader configured by CreateCreactApp's default webpack config, then by the specified JSON loader.

I don't want to eject my CRA app to modify the webpack config, and would like to avoid a re-wire hack (and whatever other issues that introduces) ... does anyone know of a way to load JSON files in a CRA app, if these files don't have a JSON extension?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that ended up working for me.

I could eject my project, of course, and customize the webpack config to load JSON files with other extensions. It may be possible to make a rewire hack work as well.

But I realized that when I require a file that is not one of the extensions recognized by CRA's config, it instead copies that file into the build, and require('file.ext') returns the URL of the file. So I'm using axios to load the file. This means a trip to the server for something that could be done statically, but for where I'm taking this project that is actually OK (eventually it will load metadata from a server anyway).